# Help with product rule word problem

Tags: calculus

> In $1999$,  the population of Richmond-Petersburg,  Virginia,  metropolitan area,  was $961{,}400$ and was increasing at roughly $9200$ people per year.  The average annual income in the area was $30{,}593$ per capita, and this average was increasing at about $\$1400$ per year. Use the product rule to estimate the rate at which total personal income was rising in the area at this time.  Explain the meaning of each term in the product rule.

So what I was thinking was that I could get

$$f(x)=961400+9200x, g(x)=30593+1400x$$

But I don't think it would make that much sense to take the product of these so that

$$f(x)g(x)=f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = (9200 \cdot 30593+1400x) + (961400+9200x \cdot  1400)$$

Is this the correct approach? If so, for what each term means, I'd say $f'(x)$ is the instantaneous rate of change of the population, $g(x)$ is the equation for the change in annual income, $f(x)$ is the equation for the change in population, and $g'(x)$ is the instantaneous rate of change of the average annual income. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you put units on you can see that multiplying them makes sense.  The units of $f$ are people, the units of $g$ are dollars/person.  When you multiply them you get total dollars of income of the city.  The terms you are to interpret are $f'(x)g(x)$ and $f(x)g'(x)$.  They each contribute to the increase in total income.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume the growths are linear. Let $P(t)$ be the number of people and let $M(t)$ be the mean income at time $t.$ The total income is $MP=M(t)P(t)$ and we have $$(MP)'=M'P+MP'=M'(t)P(t)+M(t)P'(t)\approx (1400)(961400)+(30593)(9200).$$